# React Link changes URL but doesn't refresh the view

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with `<Link to="">` element in React. After clicking it the URL changes but the view stays the same. After refreshing the page a correct component is being displayed also a router per se works fine.

Here's my code:

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <React.Fragment>
          <MainBar />
          <Sidebar />
          <Content sidebarOpen={this.state.sidebarOpen}>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                </Switch>
          </Content>
        </React.Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Sidebar.js in which I call `/about` URL. Here's an extra class `ListItemLink` to create a `Link to` with React Material `ListItem`

```
class ListItemLink extends React.Component {
  renderLink = itemProps => <Link to={this.props.to} {...itemProps} />;

  render() {
    const { icon, primary } = this.props;
    return (
      <li>
        <ListItem button component={this.renderLink}>
          <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={primary} />
        </ListItem>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Drawer >
          <List>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <ListItemLink to="/about" primary="About" icon={<StarIcon />} />
            </BrowserRouter>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

What I've already tried:

According to answers on other stackoverflow questions I've tried adding `withRouter()` here:

```
<Route path="/about" component={withRouter(About)} />
```

and also in About.js here:

```
export default withRouter(About);
```

I've also tried wrapping the Routes into a main `Route` with `Content` component like that:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Content} >
        <Route default component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: what is the usage of `BrowserRouter` in `Sidebar` ? It may not help to solve your problem but still I don't find it useful here

Comment: @Kabbany it works, haha. I am sure I had errors without it previously. Thank you! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `BrowserRouter` is not useful in `Sidebar`